# JAXB @XmlValue and @XmlElements

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Is it possible to have a JAXB element that renders with a value AND elements?

I'm trying to render something like:

```
<thing>
    <otherthing></otherthing>
    This is some text
</thing>
```

It's know probably not even valid XML, but unfortunatley, what I'm trying to render requires it and is not optional.

Having a value and elements give's a `IllegalAnnotationExceptions`.

Answer (score 1):

What you have shown is completely valid XML. An element has has `text()` and `element` children is known as [mixed content](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-mixed-content).

Use the [`@XmlMixed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlMixed.html) JAXB annotation instead of `@XmlValue` to indicate that the element is mixed content.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class Thing {

  private List<Object> mixedContent = new ArrayList<Object>();

  @XmlElementRef(name="thing", type=Thing.class)
  @XmlMixed
  public List<Object> getMixedContent() {
    return mixedContent;
  }

  public void setMixedContent(List<Object> mixedContent) {
     this.mixedContent = mixedContent;
  }

}
```